# Lets clean up this SE and answer the old unanswered!

Tags: discussion, questions, unanswered-questions

Post questions here which you feel need an answer but have gone to long without attention.

Up-vote the ones you feel are more important to answer.

Down-vote the ones you feel are just bad questions that can't be answered.

Comment if you feel the question should be closed/deleted or needs editing.

Comment: Also if you feel the question really helps the community put up a bounty :)

Comment: I applaud the effort. Many of the questions are non-US. I wonder if there's any pull of data to show the locations for top, say, 50-100, users here. The non-US question are certainly on-topic, but have far fewer writers capable of responding.

Comment: Also, if something gets a lot of downvotes, lets target it for closure.

Answer (score 2):

Please answer "[Tax due on foreign exchange element of share option program?](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/10831/6564)"

Up-vote to give me more attention, down-vote if you feel I'm a bad question and comment if I need to be closed, deleted or editing

Answer (score 1):

Please answer "[Is it possible to work out my P60 from my pay?](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/10445/6564)"

Up-vote to give me more attention, down-vote if you feel I'm a bad question and comment if I need to be closed, deleted or editing

Answer (score 1):

Please answer "[How to file/calculate a plain Net Operating Loss (NOL)](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/8225/6564)?"

Up-vote to give me more attention, down-vote if you feel I'm a bad question and comment if I need to be closed, deleted or editing

Answer (score 0):

Please answer "[Multi-user, non-US personal finance and budget software](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/14412/6564)"

Up-vote to give me more attention, down-vote if you feel I'm a bad question and comment if I need to be closed, deleted or editing

Answer (score 0):

Please answer "[Which institutions in Canada offer true read-only guest accounts?](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/11807/6564)"

Up-vote to give me more attention, down-vote if you feel I'm a bad question and comment if I need to be closed, deleted or editing

Answer (score -1):

Please answer "[Can an Individual invest in the Swiss Re Longevity Bond?](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/15201/6564)"

Up-vote to give me more attention, down-vote if you feel I'm a bad question and comment if I need to be closed, deleted or editing

Answer (score -1):

Please answer "[What is Remittance vs. Arising basis in Tax?](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/12392/6564)"

Up-vote to give me more attention, down-vote if you feel I'm a bad question and comment if I need to be closed, deleted or editing